# IsSame and IsAfter condition not working in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am validating the dates using moment.js

```
var dobfield = $("#dobfield").val().trim();
//...
formatToApply = "DD/MM/YYYY";
//...
else if(moment(dobfield, formatToApply).isAfter(moment().format(formatToApply))) 
{
    swal({
        title: "",
        text: "Date of birth has to be in the past! "
    });
    $("#dobfield").focus();
}
else if(moment(dobfield, formatToApply).isSame(moment().format(formatToApply))) 
{
    swal({
        title: "",
        text: "Date of birth cannot be in the present! "
    });
    $("#dobfield").focus();
}
```

Both the `isSame` and `isAfter` fails to validate the date given in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just want to compare just the date, not the time. So you have to indicate that to the `isSame()` and `isAfter()` functions...

```
var dobfield = $("#dobfield").val().trim();
...
formatToApply = "DD/MM/YYYY";
...
else if (moment(dobfield,formatToApply).isAfter(moment(),'day')) {

    swal({
        title: "",
        text: "Date of birth has to be in the past! "
    });
    $("#dobfield").focus();
}
else if (moment(dobfield,formatToApply).isSame(moment(),'day')) {

    swal({
        title: "",
        text: "Date of birth cannot be in the present! "
    });
    $("#dobfield").focus();
}
```

Here you have a fiddle example... https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/mz9rutuq/

NOTE: `dobfield` date format always has to match with the format specified in `formatToApply` variable. Otherwise, `moment(dobfield,formatToApply)` will get unexpected result.

Comment: Please note that formatToApply varies according to the date format kept in settings page... that is why i have keep that as variable

Comment: But you want to compare with current day, right? Then isSame and isAfter parameter don't care about the format, the accept a moment object. The comparison is independent of the format. Check this fiddle example... https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/mz9rutuq/

Comment: @user2179026 `dobfield` date format always has to match with the format specified in `formatToApply` variable. Otherwise, `moment(dobfield,formatToApply)` will get unexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly , moment.js isAfter and isSame is not wokring for this date format . it is only working for YYYY-MM-DD .

This is a bug from moment.js i could say .

Comment: No, there is no bug in moment.js, both [`isAfter`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/) and [`isSame`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) work fine if used properly. If the input is not in `YYYY-MM-DD` format it can be parsed using [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue is outdated version of moment.js